# How to enter bra-ket notation in MS OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, math-input-panel

Bracket notation is writing different brackets, surrounding single unit, including

[image]

for bra vectors and

[image]

for ket vectors.

Unfortunately, I see no such template in OneNote math:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the equation editor just type:

```
\bra|
```

followed by a space, for the bra vector brackets and:

```
|\ket
```

followed by a space, for the ket vector brackets.

For the full bra-ket inner product notation type:

```
\bra|\ket
```

followed by a space. To insert space for operators right-click on the bracket and select 'insert argument before/after" to separate the bracket into 2 or more parts

Answer (score 1):

To do it just use the single bracket list as shown in the picture and select from it the 
relevant large < or > (far right of first row in pic). Then use shift forward slash (the button next to left-shift on most keyboards) to give the vertical line |. In combination you get correct bra-ket notation.

Answer (score 1):

(For OneNote 2016, not sure for other versions)
You can write \bra and get the < , and write \ket and get the >
(And it looks just like it would in LaTeX)

Answer (score 0):

You can use encapsulation. For example if you want to create a "ket" operator, use the |-template first and then include the >-template into it. It might not be as perfect as in TeX, but the tops and bottoms of the brackets align.